# SQL. Retrieve data from the table where data is duplicated from 1 column and sifferent from another one

Tags: mysql

guys. Can you please help to resolve some issue? I have the table with 2 columns (A and B).

```
ID    A         B
1   111111     XXX
2   111111     YYY
3   222222     XXX
4   333333     ZZZ
5   333333     ZZZ
```

And I need to retrieve data where B is duplicated and at the same time A is different. I mean ID (1 and 3) should appear. Thanks in advance))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the distinct number of values `a` has per value of `b` and query the relevant ids:

```
SELECT id
FROM   mytable
WHERE  b IN (SELECT   b
             FROM     mytable
             GROUP BY b
             HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT a) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mureinik. I appreciate your quick answer. Everything works fine.